# Loopback get multipart form-data parameters

Tags: mongodb, get, strongloop, form-data, loopback

I have a file container hosting my images. I did create some additional properties for that container using `slc loopback:property` and put in a string types such as: title, description, date(date). I am able to upload my image via `api/containers/{container}/upload`

Using Advanced REST Client, I add an HTTP Header: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I then input data into my forms. I add my image and send, here is my response:
```

```
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 205
Etag: W/"cd-dUHU2bNp6fDC61813wVPRw"
Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 20:52:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

```

```

```
{
  "result": {
    "files": {
      "fileUpload2": [
        {
          "container": "images",
          "name": "pnw.png",
          "type": "image/png",
          "size": 269360
        }
      ]
    },
    "fields": {
      "created": [
        "04/20/2016"
      ],
      "title": [
        "title"
      ],
      "description": [
        "this is a description"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```

I am curious, is the `fields` object stored somewhere? (I do have mongo connector good to go) or is this in memory? I can't seem to find it anywhere and not sure how to do a GET req. My ultimate goal is to do one image post with additional parameters/properties and retrieve the same in one instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will go another route as I do not think I am understanding content-disposition correctly.